# How to animate multiple animation blueprints offseting time for each instance?

Tags: unreal, skeletal-animation, blueprints, unreal-5

I'm new to Unreal Engine and would like to get an effect similar to this one:

[image: Rei in Mirror Cave Scene in Star Wars The Last Jedi where she sees copies/reflections of herself in front and behind her offset in time]

The idea is to have an Animation BluePrint with data from a Live Link Pose node to start with. To achieve the effect, my very rough idea is something like this:

1. store incoming pose data in a (ring)buffer (e.g. 24 frames (each entry delayed by a frame))
2. create multiple instances to receive the pose data (ideally dynamically, however, if that's not possible, manually creating each would work)
3. as new pose data arrive, assign each instance a different entry in the pose data (ring) buffer, achieving the time offset effect

I understand this is multiple questions in one, but I would be grateful to any direction towards the right functionality to achieve the effect:

- Is it possible to buffer pose data as it arrives ? (If so, where do I begin ?)
- Is it possible to create multiple skinned meshes at runtime to drive with these poses ? (if not, what recommendations do you have of assigning buffered poses to manually created ones (e.g. referencing by name with an index like suffix, etc.))

(I'm using UnrealEngine 5.1 at the moment. If 5.2 makes this easier I will consider upgrading)